# Laravel\Vagrant Homestead for Symfony4 bad php version detected

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, homestead

I have problem with my symfony project. 
Overall i got this message:

```
Fatal Error: composer.lock was created for PHP version 7.4 or higher but the current PHP version is 7.2.26.
```

I tried to set php in homestead.yaml, the result was **502 Bad Gateway**

When i use php -v, i get:

```
PHP 7.4.1 (cli) (built: Dec 18 2019 14:44:22) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.1, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

I tried, to edit composer.json or composer.lock. No results - still fatal.

Another command/solution tried:

```
Composer update php
```

and the output:

Problem 1
    - This package requires php 7.2.26 but your PHP version (7.4.1) does not satisfy that requirement.

No idea what i can check/change else...

Comment: Create an `info.php` in your public directory, add `<?php phpinfo();` to it, then try to access that file. It will tell you which version of PHP is being used for the web.

Comment: I've got same result as on the top. Then i edited yaml file(removed type:symfony4), and result: No input file specified.

Comment: 7.4.1 using php -ini